# iText ListItem and List class in java

Tags: java, list, itext

I want to use iText to create a PDF. I want to create a ordered list. However, I want the way elements are marked to be:

```
a)
b)
c)
d)
etc...
```

iText doesn't support that kind of marking, as it has several of his own, predefined. Is there a way to create my own marker (e.g. constructing a string of elements and passing it to the correct method/constructor), or is the only way to tamper with the iText's core files?

The lists I intend using it on has only up to 5 elements, so the lenght of the alphabet is not a problem...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about:

```
List list = new List(List.ORDERED, List.ALPHABETICAL); 
list.setLowercase(List.LOWERCASE);
list.setPostSymbol(") "); 
// use list
```

see [`List` source](http://itext.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/itext/trunk/itext/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/text/List.java?revision=5373&view=markup)

Comment: Didn't know about the `.setPostSymbol` method!Thanks!